# Return a property value by default

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there is a way to have a default return value for a javascript object. I'll try to explain with an example:

I have:

```
Obj1 = {'prop1' = 'something1',
        'prop2' = 'something2',
        'active' = typeof XMLobj.propX === 'undefined' ? false : true} //XMLobj comes from somewhere else
```

since I want this object to be part of another object, I would like to have something like

```
If (otherObj.Obj1) { //do something using prop1 and/or prop2 }.
```

where `otherObj.Obj1` to return the value of the active field, instead of having to check for `otherObj.Obj1.active`

The reason behind is likely bad code (my fault). I wrote several functions using something using  `If (otherObj.Obj1)`. I didn't care care about it's properties at the time, but now I'd like to further expand, and I would like to avoid (if possible using somethig like this:

```
otherObj.Obj1 = typeof XMLobj.propX === 'undefined' ? false : true} //XMLobj comes from somewhere else
otherObj.Obj1Prop1 = 'something1'
otherObj.Obj1Prop2 = 'something2'
```

any advice? thanks

Comment: What browsers/engines do you wish to support?

Comment: the latest chrome and firefox will be ok, I'm not planning to deploy this online. I am actually using javascript as a XML parser (using the ObjTree.js library) . 

This is I have some quite long and complex XML files, from which I'm displaying only those nodes I'm interested in

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question. Firstly, you are missing a comma in your object literal definition of `Obj1`. Is the idea that the `active` property is supposed to tell you whether to use `prop1` or `prop2`? If so, which value is supposed to be used if `active` is true?

Comment: Or are you just asking if you can add properties to an object after you've created it? In that case, the answer is yes, just use the same dot notation you would use to retrieve values to set completely new ones: `otherObj.Obj1.someNewProperty = "foo"`

Comment: I think he wants `otherObj.Obj1` to evaluate to `otherObj.Obj1.active` when used in boolean expressions.

Comment: You can't make `otherObj.Obj1` ever return the value of `otherObj.Obj1.active` unless you actually check `otherObj.Obj1.active`.

Comment: just edited the comma, thanks. the idea is that prop1 and prop2 are being populated from parsing the XML file. then if active, I want to print the values on the screen (and html table). let's say prop1 =type of operation and prop2 = column applied to, then if( Active) I'd like to print 'Multiply Quantity' or 'Sum Costs'. Before I used to say 'There is/isn't an operation present' (no more info about it)

Comment: acdjunior, yes I think that summarize my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript won't return a field from an object when simply referencing the object.  It must return the object itself.  In some languages which have static typing information, this can happen (I think VB did this).  JavaScript has no static typing, so it needs to return the object.  It would have no way of telling when to return the object and when to return the 'default' field within the object.

Comment: "JavaScript has no static typing, so it needs to return the object." is not technically true.  Just because JS doesn't have apparent static typing doesn't preclude it from inspecting the object and calling a special method (like how String(foo) calls foo's toString)

Comment: @Nirk:  It sure does, if you ever want to access the other properties of the object.  For example, "yourObj.prop1" could never be read if "yourObj" access always returned the value for "prop2".  (Unless "prop2" was an object which also held "prop1"...)  BTW, if you downvoted for that, please fix it.  The answer is correct with regards to JavaScript behavior, even if you debate a technical issue of the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect object literal notation:

```
Obj1 = {'prop1' = 'something1',
        'prop2' = 'something2',
        'active' = true or false}
```

Should be:

```
var someCondition = // Make this evaluate to true or false based on whether it's active.
var otherObj = {Obj1 : {prop1: 'something1',
        prop2: 'something2',
        active: someCondition ? true : false}
        };
```

The normal way to check the `active` property of the object:

```
if(otherObj.Obj1.active) { //do something using prop1 and/or prop2 }.
```

If you do this: `otherObj.Obj1 = true;` you are wiping out your object

Comment: yes, sorry for the bad notation. I meant that active could be either true or false. it will actually come from something like 
 typeof  XMLobj.propX === 'undefined' ? false : true